# Which java datatype to use in a hibernate entity to represent id colum in a database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, entity-framework, hibernate

I am designing a database for a web application. I am using Hibernate ORM framework to persist data to the database.

I was wondering which java data type should i use to represent the id columns? in the entity

I started out by creating the tables with id columns with data type **int** but then i just started feeling that long or Big Decimal would be better..

So which datatype would be better and how to make a choice?

Can i get an architectural or a performance view if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are starting with a fresh DB I would recommend a long (to support a lot of transactions in the long run). The main advantages of having a long as Id are as below:

1. You can use a sequence to generate the unique Id's
2. though int is a sufficient large value( 2,147,483,647), however if you are dealing with a transactional table (like storing audit information) it might get exhausted in the long run (assuming your application will run for 3 years. Long will comparatively be more flexible.

BigDecimal is redundant if you ask me because id's would ideally NOT be a decimal value but a whole number

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the data type you want. 
If you want your Id to be alphanumeric use, String, or if you want it to be a random or a requence number, prefer long..

Though it isn't even necessary to have an Id field in your model just like a version field, it will be managed by hibernate, which by default would be a running number. 
Using @Id annotation.

Refer: http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html#Id

You can also specify an Id generation strategy using the @GeneratedValue annotation

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE ,generator="account_user_id_seq")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Long, as is the default mapping for integer on most databases.